# Need an example data for PVF package(Photo Voltaic and Solar Forecasting)

Tags: r, forecasting

I am working on PV forecasting(predicting the AC power that can be generated by a solar power plant). I am trying to use PVF package for that.

I tried to see how to use that package, but there is no sample data given for this package. The package is available at https://github.com/iesiee/PVF

There is nothing given in Readme.md file too.

It would be of great help if someone can get me an example dataset to work with PVF package.

I am seriously struggling on how to start working on it as I don't have any data and flow of functions of what to use.

You can suggest if there is a way I can contact the contributor.

Comment: You can contact(chat) him in his SO Profile which can be found - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/964866/oscar-perpi%C3%B1%C3%A1n). Once you get something please let us know the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I have texted him via SO chat. Will let you know once I get any reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meteorological data was retrieved from [Meteogalicia](http://www.meteogalicia.es) using the [meteoForecast package](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/meteoForecast). The output power was obtained from actual measurements of private PV plants. We are not allowed to publish these datasets, but the package is designed to work with almost any file.

Both meteorological data and power measurements were combined to be used as
input to the prediction functions from PVF package as described in this [paper](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/papers/Pinho.Perpinan.ea2014.pdf) and in the help pages of the package and its functions.